# Why is my application searching the wrong DLL for a function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker

I am writing a Qt Application using Visual Studio 2010. My application 'Review.exe' links against `QtAV.dll` using `QtAV.lib`. In turn, QtAV links against ffmpeg, portaudio, gdiplus, etc.

The debug version works correctly.

When I try and run the release version I get:
The procedure entry point `GdipAlloc` could not be located in the dynamic link library `avcodec-54.dll`.

`GdipAlloc` is a part of `Gdiplus`.  Why is the wrong dll being searched for the function? This only happens in the release build.

If I replace the release version of `QtAV.dll` with the debug version of `QtAV.dll`, the release version of Review will load the debug version of `QtAV.dll`.

Setting the linker flag `/DEBUG` on the release build causes the problem to go away. However I'd like to figure out the cause and a proper solution.

Comment: It depends on if you have two copies/versions of the DLL and where they are located. If you have two of them one may be compiled with options the other is not.

Answer (score 0):

I find that it does happens for vs2010. vs2012 works fine. I compile portaudio by vs2010 again(use cmake is quite easy), and generate FFmpeg .lib files by vs2010 tools, then compile QtAV again, this errors disappears!
I have uploaded new development files to build QtAV. Download FFmpeg-2.0.1_mingw32+msvc.7z and portaudio-v19_msvc2010x86_20130813.7z here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/qtav/files/depends

: )